# Express app.get() equivalent in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, phantomjs, casperjs

I have built a simple web scraper that scrapes a website and outputs the data I need when I visit this URL - `localhost:3434/page`. I implemented this functionality using the express `app.get()` method.

I have the following questions,

1) I want to know if there is a way to implement this functionality in CasperJS.

2) Is there a way to make this code start scraping after I visit the URL -`localhost:8081/scrape`. I don't think I am creating the endpoint correctly because it is starting the scrape before I even visit the URL

3) When I visit the URL it gives me an error saying that the URL is not available.

I think all of these problems will be solved if I can set the end point correctly to `localhost:3434/page` in CasperJS. I don't need the results to appear on the page. I only need it to start scraping when I visit that URL.

Below is the code I developed to scrape a website and create a server in Casper.

```
var server = require('webserver').create();

var service = server.listen(3434, function(request, response) {
    var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel:"verbose",
    debug:true
    });

    var links;
    var name;
    var paragraph;
    var firstName;
    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    casper.start('http://www.home.com/professionals/c/oho,-TN');

    casper.then(function getLinks(){
         links = this.evaluate(function(){
            var links = document.getElementsByClassName('pro-title');
            links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
                return link.getAttribute('href');
            });
            return links;
        });
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        this.each(links,function(self,link){
          if (link.match(regex)) {
            self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
              var firstName = this.fetchText('div.info-list-text');
              this.echo(firstName);
            });
          }
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.write(firstName);
            response.close();              
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `webserver` you used in your CasperJS script is PhantomJS's [Web Server Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver) which is *"intended for ease of communication between PhantomJS scripts and the outside world and is **not** recommended for use as a general production server"*

You should not build your web server in PhantomJS. Checkout these node-phantom bridges that will let you use Phantom from your regular NodeJS web server:

- https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS
- https://github.com/peerigon/phridge
- https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple
- https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman
- https://github.com/nodeca/navit

SpookyJS is a driver particularly for CasperJS, whereas others are for PhantomJS only.

Although [CasperJS allows being loaded from within PhantomJS](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-casperjs-without-using-the-casperjs-executable) so you can at least use it in Phridge (not sure about others) since it has a `.run` function which runs any function directly inside PhantomJS environment:

```
casperPath = path.join(require.resolve('casperjs/bin/bootstrap'), '/../..');
phantom.run(casperPath, function(casperPath) {
    phantom.casperPath = casperPath;
    phantom.injectJs(casperPath + '/bin/bootstrap.js');
    casper = require('casper').create();
    ...
```

---

Besides the ones that use PhantomJS, there's also others:

- https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare
- https://github.com/assaf/zombie

ZombieJS uses native NodeJS libraries which makes it the fastest and most natural to use in a NodeJS app. Although it's meant more for testing purposes and may not work on all sites that other scrapers might.